# Issue with Excel into Word then export to PDF

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ms-word, ms-office

I am currently with a problem. I am creating a reporting system in C#. It uses Excel and Word. The system generates a Word document and then imports the Excel document into the Word document.

The problem is as follows:
If I have a Word document with red text export to PDF I get the neat red. Same with a standard Excel export.

**But!** I want do do this:

- **Make a Excel** document with (for example) red text
- **Import the Excel** document in Word
- **Export the Word** document to a PDF

So the million dollar question is:

How can i keep the coloured text from excel when i export my Word to PDF ! :-D

I really appriciate any help! And i might throw in a bounty if the question stays open for a while.

**Note**: The color is still good when i import the Excel into Word.

Edit: I use the Office 2010 for generating the report

Edit2:[image: Why i cant skip Excel]

Comment: I think its going into the direction of a bug report towards Microsoft...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a trial version of [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx).

That will handle the creation of Word documents and output to PDF, and in my experience it's a really good tool.

Comment: To be honest exporting a pdf works fine. Its the export from an internal Excel object in Word that fails to export correctly. Also i really prefer no not use additional dependencies then the Office installation.

Comment: Depending on office installation is something that most people try to avoid. Interop isn't the most friendliest thing on earth and it can bite you in the ass in the most non-expected moment.

Comment: @Programmer XR: Sorry, it looks from your question like you're losing the styles when you export to PDF.  Is that not the case?  As @MadBoy says, would it not be simpler to skip the Excel stage and just output the report straight into a Word document?

Comment: Can't skip the Excel part, unless you know a way to create the same layout in Word. I'll add a picture to the post in a min.

Comment: @Programmer XR: Ah, I see what you mean.  How are you currently doing the export to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what you're trying to do with Excel that it has to be created with Excel first then moved into Word and then moved into PDF ? Sounds like it's really something you may want to look at first.

Check [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) for creating Word document directly (creating tables, making nice layouts etc). And then just convert it to PDF. It's easy and nicely done. It's also server-safe.

Unless there's very specific need to create Excel first I would avoid it.

Comment: The Excel document contains Graphs and calculations that Word can't create. Ill update the post in a bit to contain a picture of the Excel. Word is used for extra information ( Tables / User defined remarks / etc. )

Answer (score 0):

Programmer XP,

I am not sure why the "MS Word" section is in your workflow.
You start with Excel and want a PDF, why not use a PDF creator.
I have used various free PDF creators in macro's to convert (sections) of a spreadsheet into PDF's by "printing" to the PDF service.

Check out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/

This way you can skip the "MS Word" part, unless you are adding/combining the excel spreadsheet to an existing document.

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink